# Incompatible react native SDK with expo SDK

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo, expo-go

When I run react native project using expo I got this error "This project uses SDK 38.0.0 but this version of Expo Go only supports the following SDKs: 43.00, 42.0.0, 41.0.0, 40.0.0. To load the project, it must be updated to a supported SDK version or an older version of Expo Go must be used"
I already installed all my needed packages in the project so  how to solve it?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.1",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
```

Answer (score 14):

You have to upgrade your expo SDK to latest one

use

```
expo upgrade
```

But if you have some packages which are depreciated then you don't have any option you have to create new expo project with and face little bit of efforts to rearrange them all

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to update your version of the Expo SDK using the "expo upgrade" command.
This error is saying that your SDK version should be 43 down to 40, but your current version, as listed in the dependencies, is 38.0.8

Here are some resources for upgrading your version of the SDK from the official docs:
https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Note that they recommend upgrading your version of the SDK incrementally, so be cautious when performing upgrades as it could break your app if done carelessly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 expo upgrade
```

is deprecated. you need to have `expo-cli` installed and on your terminal

```
expo-cli upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of EAS CLI (if you use it):

```
npm i -g eas-cli
```

Install the new version of the Expo package:

`npm install expo@^48.0.0` or `yarn add expo@^48.0.0`

Upgrade all dependencies to match SDK 48:

```
npx expo install --fix
```

**after upgrade all dependencies**

Clear cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Run your project :
`npx expo start` or `npx expo start --tunnel`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this `expo upgrade 49.0.0`, write version which you want to install

Answer (score 0):

expo upgrade is deprecated. Now you need to update expo in this way:

`npx expo-cli upgrade`