# Expo version 44 to 47 expo upgrade error: Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg, metro-bundler

I just cloned the repository;
"https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/tree/master/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase"
and did:
`yarn run start`;
Then in my mi note 10 expo go app:

```
This project uses SDK 44.0.0, but this version of Expo Go only supports the following SDK's: 
47.0.0, 46.0.0, 45.0.0 
To load the project it must be updated to a supported SDK version or an older version of 
Expo Go must be used.
```

and after I tried to upgrade expo
`expo upgrade`
the error shown:

```
Warning! Your git working tree is dirty.
It's recommended to commit all your changes before proceeding, so you can revert the changes made by this command if necessary.

√ Would you like to proceed? ... yes

√ You are currently using SDK 44.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest version, 47.0.0? ... yes


× Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:314:31)
    at YarnPackageManager.addWithParametersAsync (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:259:16)
    at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:263:5)
    at upgradeAsync (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\info\upgradeAsync.ts:496:7)
    at actionAsync (C:\Users\justi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\info\upgradeAsync.ts:42:3)
```

I also followed deleted the node_modules .expo folders in each of the folders: Expo and Next folders, also I tried to upgrade expo 44 version to 47
according those links:

[Incompatible react native SDK with expo SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70328652/incompatible-react-native-sdk-with-expo-sdk)
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21026
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16293

Also I tried to:
`npx expo start`

```
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
› Port 19000 is
√ Use port 19001 instead? ... yes
Starting project at D:\Belgeler\VScode\NativeBaseSolito\nativebase-templates\solito-universal-app-template-nativebase
Starting Metro Bundler
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀▀ ██▄█  █ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ █▄▀██▀██ ▀█ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █ ▄ █ █▀ ██ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ █ ▀▄█▄█▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█▄ ▀ ▀█▄▄▀▀█   ▀▄▄▀  ▄▀▄▄▀█
█▀▄▄▀  ▄  ▀▀   ▄▀▄▄▀ ▀▀█▄▄█
█▄▀███▄▄▄▄█▄ █  █▀█ ▄█ ██▀█
█▄▀▀▀▀▀▄█ █▄ █▀▀█ ▄▄ ▀▀██▄█
█▄▄██▄▄▄█ ▀██ ▀▄  ▄▄▄ █ ▄ █
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄  ▄ █▄  █▄█  ▀ ▄█
█ █   █ █▀ ▄▀▄ ▀▀▄ ▄▄ █▀▄██
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀ ▀██  █  █▄  ▄█▄█
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄███▄▄█▄███▄▄█▄▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.68:19001
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (D:\Belgeler\VScode\NativeBaseSolito\nativebase-templates\solito-universal-app-template-nativebase\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)     
    at Object.getCacheKey (D:\Belgeler\VScode\NativeBaseSolito\nativebase-templates\solito-universal-app-template-nativebase\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js:647:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (D:\Belgeler\VScode\NativeBaseSolito\nativebase-templates\solito-universal-app-template-nativebase\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\getTransformCacheKey.js:32:19)
    at new Transformer (D:\Belgeler\VScode\NativeBaseSolito\nativebase-templates\solito-universal-app-template-nativebase\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:180:28)
    at D:\Belgeler\VScode\NativeBaseSolito\nativebase-templates\solito-universal-app-template-nativebase\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:58:29 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

and after I used QR code to enter the app and the error same ExpoGo APK
SDK 44 to SDK 47 is shown.

Now I will be trying to downgrade my expo go version of my phone apk if its possible. Any help will be appreciated.

I was expecting after; git clone and yarn install the project.
Everything should be good to go for a new project using this template.

Versions:

1. expo version 6.3.1
2. yarn version 1.22.19
3. npm version 8.19.2
4. node version 18.12.1

Android APK:

> expo go latest: 2.26.6

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by following these steps:

1. delete yarn.lock
2. delete node_modules
3. run yarn install
4. run expo upgrade